The JWs teach millions living in the past will gain salvation at the 2nd coming of Jesus Christ. The Bible contradicts that teaching
The source can be find here: https://www.jw.org/en/jehovahs-witnesses/faq/who-saved/

Do Jehovah’s Witnesses Feel That They Are the Only People Who Will Be Saved?


No. Many millions who lived in centuries past and who weren’t Jehovah’s Witnesses will have an opportunity for salvation. The Bible explains that in God’s promised new world, “there is going to be a resurrection of both the righteous and the unrighteous.” (Acts 24:15) Additionally, many now living may yet begin to serve God, and they too will gain salvation. In any case, it’s not our job to judge who will or won’t be saved. That assignment rests squarely in Jesus’ hands.—John 5:22, 27."

How do they reconcile this viewpoint when the Bible teaches that people received/gain salvation by believing in Jesus Christ as their Savior centuries before the second coming of Jesus Christ?
Romans 10:8-10, "But what does it say? "The Word is near you, in your mouth and in your heart--that is, the word of faith which we are preaching, vs9, that if you confess with your mouth Jesus as Lord and believe in your heart that God raised Him from the dead, you will be saved; vs10, for with the heart man believes resulting in righteousness, and with the mouth he confesses resulting in salvation."

Related https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/63934/23657

@007 This does not address my specific question? How do you explain people receiving salvation BEFORE the resurrection of the righteous and unrighteous at the second coming?

Where does jw teach that?

Right here: Read the first paragraph. https://www.jw.org/en/jehovahs-witnesses/faq/who-saved/ i thought you knew your stuff?

I will explain it starting at the book of Acts. People became Christians starting in the book of Acts. The book of Acts is a "narrative" which means it's describing how the church got started. Look at it like it's a history book if you will. So it's a given that people were born again or became Christians right away after the resurrection of Jesus Christ. What you teach is salvation will be realized in God's promised new World and people will gain salvation there. You even quoted Acts 24:15. My point is that salvation has been achieved from Acts 2 to present day. Do you see the contradiction

Maybe include some of that line of reasoning in the question

I tried that in previous threads on this subject when I quoted Acts 10: and how Corneilus and his household received salvation well before what you Jw's stated but it closed thinking I was asking a similar question, which was not. In fact, your were the main "cheer leader" to get rid of it, that's why?

You have put your own case clearly enough @Mr.Bond but I feel you have not sufficiently documented (or explained) the argument that you are opposing. There is a sense in which 'salvation' is not fully realised until the resurrection when the full redemption of sons is accomplished in a new humanity, new heavens and a new earth. And I think (though I am uncertain) that this aspect is complicating the comparison of two schools of thought who are expressing doctrine in very different ways.

My argument is simple Nigel. The Jehovah's Witnesses teach one does not gain salvation until the new world arrives which is at the second coming when Jesus will judge the righteous and unrighteous. I've explained as clear as possible that people gained salvation by believing in Jesus Christ at the start of the book of Acts. Three thousand were added to Church at Acts 2. I also gave Acts 10, the house of Cornelius a Gentile who was given the Holy Spirit. I don't understand why that is not clear?

I've read this several times, and I still don't understand what you think the contradiction is. If the question were to present two distinct and as short and simple as possible statements that obviously contradict each other, I might understand. But as it sits now all I see is a bunch of hand waving that doesn't present any actual problem.

To clarify what I just said. What I read here is maybe ten statements, including in the quoted text, with which I would more or less agree, and a question about how to reconcile them. But I have no idea exactly which of those statements need to be reconciled, as they all seem to fit together quite well. Obviously you see something here that I don't, but the question needs to make it explicit.

Ok, first of the all 007 is a Jw and he edited my original question an hour ago. So read the question as is and ask yourself WHEN will people who are not Jw,s receive salvation? I'm saying people already have salvation when they believed in My Jesus Christ. My proof is from the book of Acts. Now at the top of the question click on the "Teaching is explained here." When you read it they explain salvation is gained in the new world when the righteous and unrighteous of us are judged. This is after the second coming. And they proved it by quoting Acts 24:15. Does in it now make sense? I hope!

My edit only linked to the source you quoted from and highlighted the quote

@Mr.Bond says "I'm saying people already have salvation when they believed in My Jesus Christ. My proof is from the book of Acts."
I don't see how that is proof.
Your quotation from Acts only says that three thousand people joined the Church; it doesn't say they all received salvation at that time.

Well 007, how are you going to respond? Please reconcile your view with what the Bible teaches where a person receives salvation when they believe on the Lord Jesus Christ? Just like the thief on cross did. Jesus told him he would be in Paradise that day, not in the new world and after the second coming.

@Ray Butterworth. In order to join the Catholic/universal church what did they do according to the Apostle Peter at Acts 2:37-38? They received the gift of the Holy Spirit which means they received salvation on that day. And look at Acts 10 where Peter went to the Gentiles, specifically  the house of Cornelius a Roman soldier.  At Acts 10:44 Peter was speaking and the Holy Spirit fell upon those who were listening. At vs45 they received the Holy Spirit and then at vs 47-48 they were water baptized. Notice they received the gift of the Holy Spirit first, and then they were baptized.

Related https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59541/what-is-the-jehovahs-witness-perspective-on-salvation/59567?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C37.8803#59567

Related https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/79215/can-a-jehovahs-witness-say-that-they-know-they-have-eternal-life

The Jehovah witness teaching is correct because the righteous dead will be raised first and then the wicked second. It is clearly stated in the Bible

Jesus Christ Himself was baptized,what makes anyone think they can inherit the kingdom without being baptized ,unless one is born again by spirit and water

Those 3000 souls added were Jehovahs witnesses according to JWs. JWs teach that theirs is a restoration of true worship matching as closely as possible the Christian congregation in its infancy before the apostasy set in bringing corrupt teachings like the ones OP espouses. (OSAS)

Nothing in linked material says that those millions will gain salvation at the Jesus' 2nd coming. It refers to "an opportunity" but does not say that it will be at Jesus' 2nd coming.

From the comments, it's finally become apparent that this question has nothing to do with Jehovah's Witnesses.
The OP is actually asking why most Christian denominations don't accept one of his doctrines.
Unfortunately this belief is nowhere actually mentioned in the question.
The OP seemingly assumes that everyone else already understands and believes it.
In fact, this is a relatively recent doctrine, not accepted by most denominations, including the Catholic Church, whose views on this issue aren't much different from those of Jehovah's Witnesses:

…, some Protestants advocate an idea known as eternal security.
According to this view, if a person ever enters a state of salvation, he will remain in it for all eternity.
It thus is not possible to lose salvation.
This view was unheard of in Church history prior to the Reformation.
Prior Christians universally acknowledged that salvation was granted through baptism, but it also was clear that some of the baptized later committed sins that the New Testament says will exclude one from the kingdom of heaven.
Therefore, the idea of eternal security was a theological novelty when it was proposed in the 1500s.
…
Another view of eternal security is sometimes expressed with the phrase “once saved, always saved.” This view is found among some non-Calvinist Protestants, and it holds that true Christians can and do fall away from the faith or fall permanently into grievous sin, yet they do not lose their salvation.
A single moment of saving faith, at any point in one’s life, is sufficient to permanently cancel all of one’s sins, even those not yet committed.
Therefore—at least in terms of salvation—it does not matter what one later does.
This view is often associated with advocates of free grace theology.
…
The Catholic Church recognizes, based on the clear teaching of the New Testament, that it is possible for Christians to lose their salvation. St. Paul explicitly warns Judaizing Christians, “You are severed from Christ, you who would be justified by the Law; you have fallen away from grace” (Gal. 5:4). He also tells his audience of Corinthian Christians, “Do you not know that the unrighteous will not inherit the kingdom of God? Do not be deceived,” and he goes on to list multiple sins, warning that those who commit them will not “inherit the kingdom of God” (1 Cor. 6:9–10).
— Can Salvation Be Lost? | Catholic Answers Magazine

Also see Eternal security - Wikipedia.

Yes, agreed. This is the complication which renders the question moot - the definition of 'salvation'. A once-saved-always-saved immediate 'decision' ? Or an extraordinary gift from God which has several aspects, many applications and is ongoing to the very day of judgment and beyond. Up-voted +1.

There are a lot of crossed wires here, causing sparks to fly! One authentic Jehovah's Witness source that shows exactly what they believe regarding the resurrection of the millions of humans (after Armageddon), and according to the complicated scheme of theology of the Witnesses, is to be found in Insight on the Scriptures Vol.2, pp 785-793
There is far too much in that large section to explain here, but anyone asking any questions about their beliefs regarding resurrection and salvation must study their theology first. When that has not been fully done, questions suppose certain things to be what they teach, which they do not teach at all. Then such questions get closed down. Yet the underlying query at back of this question is important, so, without providing any group a platform for promoting their particular teachings, let me just answer this way.
The Jehovah's Witnesses claim that salvation for those on Earth will only be obtained by those who keep obedient during the 1,000 year Millennium on Earth. Nobody gets salvation immediately after Armageddon (which, for them, is Christ's 3rd coming, or presence). The millennium only provides "an opportunity"; they have to work constantly at obedience to the leaders (in heaven, and with some representatives on Earth) during all of that time to be eventually saved, and if they pass the final test. Note this sentence correctly quoted in the question, but misunderstood by many:

"...millions who lived in centuries past and who weren’t Jehovah’s
Witnesses will have an opportunity for salvation" (emphasis
mine)

Having cleared that up, going back to the drawing board to design a third attempt at framing a question about this would not go amiss, I suggest.

The following response is an attempt to briefly touch on all the subjects the OP question entails, which is fairly large in scope.
Jehovah's Witnesses believe in a two-fold hope of salvation: a heavenly hope for the 144,000 spirit-anointed Christians who will reign with Christ in heaven, and an earthly hope for the vast majority who will live forever on a restored paradise earth. Both hopes are seen as integral parts of God's plan for humanity, with the anointed ones playing a crucial role in bringing about and administering the blessings of God's Kingdom to the faithful on earth.
Biblical Basis for heavenly hope

Revelation 7:4 and Revelation 14:1-3 mention the 144,000 who have been "bought from the earth."
Luke 12:32 refers to the "little flock" who are given the kingdom.

How do Jehovah’s Witnesses understand salvation?
To keep it short, salvation for JWs means complete sanctification (attaining spiritual perfection) in God’s eyes, which fully reconciles us with God (2 Corinthians 5:18-20). For spirit-anointed Christians who have been faithful til their human live‘s end, this immediately materializes in their resurrection in heaven where they will receive an incorruptible spiritual body: „flesh and blood cannot inherit God’s Kingdom, nor does corruption inherit incorruption.“ (1 Corinthians 15:50)

Jesus taught that for a “little flock,” salvation means their being
resurrected to heavenly life to share with Christ in Kingdom rule.
(Luke 12:32) - What is salvation?

Biblical Basis for earthly hope:

Revelation 7:9 describes a "great crowd" that no one could number, standing before God's throne.
John 10:16 speaks of "other sheep" that are not of the initial fold but are brought together to be part of one flock under one shepherd.

For People with an earthly hope, salvation is not immediate. These humans will not immediately receive an incorruptible body, but will continue to working out of their salvation and full sanctification and reconciliation with God under the rulership of Jesus and his 144,000 co-heirs of God’s Kingdom. After a final attempt of the Devil to mislead the earth, and the annihilation of the Devil and his demons, humans on earth will undergo the ‚final judgment‘, with those having been faithful being fully reconciled with God, turning from a state of spiritual death (in God‘s eyes) to life (Revelation 20:5, 11-15) - their salvation becoming thus finalized.

For the rest of mankind, salvation means a restoration to the perfect
life and relationship with God that Adam and Eve enjoyed in the garden
of Eden before they sinned. (Acts 3:21; Ephesians 1:10) Everlasting
life under such paradisaic conditions was God’s original purpose for
mankind. (Genesis 1:28; Mark 10:30)  - What is salvation?

The Jehovah’s Witnesses' teaching that many millions who lived in centuries past and were not Jehovah’s Witnesses will have an opportunity for salvation is based on their interpretation of scriptures such as Acts 24:15 and John 5:22, 27, which emphasize the resurrection of both the righteous and the unrighteous and the role of Jesus as the judge.
To reconcile this with Acts 2:41-42, let’s first look at the verses in question:
Acts 2:41-42 (NIV):
41 Those who accepted his message were baptized, and about three thousand were added to their number that day.
42 They devoted themselves to the apostles’ teaching and to fellowship, to the breaking of bread and to prayer.
These verses describe the immediate aftermath of Peter’s sermon at Pentecost, where about three thousand people were baptized and joined the early Christian community, dedicating themselves to the apostles’ teaching, fellowship, breaking of bread, and prayer.
Jehovah’s Witnesses understand these verses as describing the initial response to the preaching of the gospel at a specific historical moment, emphasizing the importance of baptism and community among the early believers. However, they would not see this as contradicting the broader hope of resurrection and judgment for all humanity, as indicated in other scriptures.
Their reconciliation approach might be as follows:

Future Opportunity for Salvation: Jehovah’s Witnesses believe that death paid the wages of a person’s sinful nature throughout their lives (no matter how long or short it was) - Romans 6:23. As such resurrection is possible for all, depending on Jesus’ judgment. They interpret Acts 24:15 to mean that there will be a resurrection of both the righteous and the unrighteous in the future, providing an opportunity for those who did not have the chance to hear and respond to the gospel message in their lifetimes.

Jesus as Judge: According to John 5:22, 27, Jesus has been given authority to judge. Jehovah’s Witnesses hold that Jesus will judge all people, including those who lived before the Christian era or who never heard the gospel. This judgment will take into account their actions and the opportunities they had during their lives.

Non-Judgmental Stance: As emphasized in the quoted teaching, it is not the responsibility of individuals to judge who will or will not be saved; that role is reserved for Jesus. This perspective allows for the belief that many who did not have the opportunity to become Jehovah’s Witnesses in their lifetimes may still attain salvation through Jesus’ judgment in the resurrection.


In summary, while Acts 2:41-42 highlights the immediate response to the apostles’ preaching and the growth of the early Christian community, Jehovah’s Witnesses see this as part of the larger biblical narrative. They believe that the promise of resurrection and judgment through Jesus encompasses all of humanity, providing an opportunity for salvation even for those who did not hear the gospel during their lifetimes. This belief is rooted in their interpretation of scriptures such as Acts 24:15 and John 5:22, 27.
To address how Jehovah’s Witnesses reconcile their teachings with Hebrews 9:27 and 2 Corinthians 6:2, let's first examine these verses in their context:
Hebrews 9:27 (NIV):
27 Just as people are destined to die once, and after that to face judgment,
2 Corinthians 6:2 (NIV):
2 For he says, "In the time of my favor I heard you, and in the day of salvation I helped you." I tell you, now is the time of God’s favor, now is the day of salvation.
Reconciliation of Hebrews 9:27
Jehovah’s Witnesses interpret Hebrews 9:27 to affirm that each person dies once and then faces judgment. They reconcile this with their teaching by emphasizing that judgment occurs after resurrection:

Resurrection and Judgment: They believe that after death, individuals are in a state of non-existence until the resurrection. Once resurrected, they face judgment based on their deeds and the opportunities they had during their lifetime and potentially during the Millennial Reign of Christ.

Second Chance through Resurrection: The judgment mentioned in Hebrews 9:27 is seen as a future event post-resurrection. For those who did not have the opportunity to learn about and serve God in their previous life, the resurrection provides a second chance to do so before final judgment.


Reconciliation of 2 Corinthians 6:2
Jehovah’s Witnesses view 2 Corinthians 6:2, where Paul emphasizes the immediacy of salvation, as addressing the urgency of responding to God's message in the present life:

Immediate Response Encouraged: Paul’s statement underscores the importance of taking immediate action when one hears the message of salvation. For Jehovah’s Witnesses, this means that those who hear and understand God's message today should respond without delay.

Salvation in the Present and Future: While recognizing the need for immediate action, Jehovah’s Witnesses also teach that ultimate salvation, in its fullest sense, will be realized in God’s promised new world. The present time is crucial for making decisions that will affect one's future judgment, but the complete fulfillment of salvation includes the resurrection and living under God's Kingdom.

Expanded Opportunity: They believe that the “day of salvation” can also extend into the future for those who have not yet had the opportunity to learn about Jehovah. This includes the period of Christ’s Millennial Reign when those resurrected will have the opportunity to learn and follow God's ways.


Summary
Jehovah’s Witnesses reconcile Hebrews 9:27 and 2 Corinthians 6:2 with their teachings by viewing judgment as a future event post-resurrection and by emphasizing the importance of responding to God's message now while also believing in expanded opportunities for those who have not yet had the chance to learn about Jehovah. This belief system maintains the urgency of salvation in the present while also allowing for future opportunities during the resurrection and Christ’s Millennial Reign.
Jehovah's Witnesses do not believe that the outpouring of the Holy Spirit automatically guarantees eternal salvation. Instead, they view it as part of the process of being chosen for a special role within God's purpose, particularly for those who have the hope of heavenly life.
Understanding the Outpouring of the Holy Spirit

Anointing of the Holy Spirit: Jehovah's Witnesses teach that the anointing with the Holy Spirit marks individuals as having a special heavenly calling. These individuals, referred to as the "anointed," have the hope of ruling with Christ in heaven. This anointing is not seen as an automatic guarantee of salvation but rather as a calling that requires faithfulness.

Living Faithfully: Those anointed with the Holy Spirit must remain faithful and obedient to God's commandments throughout their lives. They are expected to endure trials and remain loyal to Jehovah to receive their heavenly reward.


Salvation for the "Great Crowd"

Earthly Hope: For the majority of Jehovah's Witnesses who are not anointed, the hope is to live forever on a paradise earth. These individuals are part of the "great crowd" mentioned in Revelation 7:9-10. They receive the Holy Spirit to help them live in harmony with God's will, but their salvation is contingent on their faithful adherence to God's commandments and their support of Christ's brothers (the anointed).

Faith and Works: Jehovah's Witnesses believe that both faith and works are necessary for salvation. They emphasize that faith without works is dead, as stated in James 2:26. This means that living in accordance with God's principles and actively participating in the faith are essential for both groups (the anointed and the great crowd).


Conditional Nature of Salvation

No Predestination: Jehovah's Witnesses reject the concept of predestination, where salvation is unconditionally guaranteed. They believe that every individual has free will and must choose to serve God. Salvation is conditional upon maintaining faithfulness and loyalty to Jehovah until the end of one's life or until the end of the current system of things.

Possibility of Falling Away: Even those anointed with the Holy Spirit can lose their heavenly hope if they turn away from God and engage in unrepentant sinful behavior. Similarly, those with the earthly hope can lose the prospect of everlasting life if they fail to remain faithful.


Conclusion
In summary, Jehovah's Witnesses believe that the outpouring of the Holy Spirit is an important aspect of their faith, marking individuals for a special role in God's purpose. However, it does not automatically guarantee eternal salvation. Both anointed individuals and those with an earthly hope must remain faithful and obedient to Jehovah throughout their lives to attain salvation. Salvation is viewed as a process that involves ongoing faithfulness, obedience, and active participation in the faith.

As stated, this is opinion. No substantiation has been added. No citation, no reference, no support. Therefore one must accept it is the opinion of the writer and no-one else's..

@NigelJ that makes it a perfect match for the question!!

Well. the question has changed (again) so this no longer answers the new question, references or not.
